# VS2012 error every time I start. Message is not helpful - any suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

WHen I start VS2012 I always get an exception tellng me to look at ActivityLog.xml.  Here is what I see- useless to me.  Hoping someone else has seen this before.
Also - VS2012 eats 100% of the CPU on the machine at time.  Hoping the two are related and fixable.

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
> 
> 1) The current type, SquaredInfinity.Foundation.Configuration.Services.IConfigurationService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
> 
> Resulting in: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "SquaredInfinity.Foundation.Configuration.Services.IConfigurationService", name = "(none)".
> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, SquaredInfinity.Foundation.Configuration.Services.IConfigurationService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
> -----------------------------------------------
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
> 
>   Resolving SquaredInfinity.Foundation.Configuration.Services.IConfigurationService,(none)
> 
> 
> Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type '#Btb.#Rtb'.
> 
> Resulting in: Cannot activate part '#Btb.#Rtb'.
> Element: #Btb.#Rtb -->  #Btb.#Rtb
> 
> Resulting in: Cannot get export '#Btb.#Rtb (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.IClassifierProvider")' from part '#Btb.#Rtb'.
> Element: #Btb.#Rtb (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.IClassifierProvider") -->  #Btb.#Rtb
> 
>    at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)
>    at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)
>    at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
>    at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
>    at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)
>    at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfTM&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InvokeMatchingFactories[TExtensionInstance,TExtensionFactory,TMetadataView](IEnumerable`1 lazyFactories, Func`2 getter, IContentType dataContentType, Object errorSource)

Comment: Disable the VSCommands add-in.  Contact SquaredInfinity for support.

Answer (score 3):

Is your VSCommands extension up to date? 
There was a compatibility issue which could produce similar stack trace, and it was fixed in [latest release](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8).

Comment: They just publshed an update a week or so ago to fix a co-workers problem. They are pretty fast to assist.